# Windows 7 taskbar hides other windows' status bar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

On Windows 7, when I maximize an application window, like MS Word for example, the status bar of that app becomes hidden behind the Windows 7 Taskbar instead of docking itself at full screen mode, above the taskbar.

Can I change it so when I maximize the window, it'll take up all the screen space that is ABOVE the task bar?

Comment: Yep that did the trick.

Comment: trick below didnt work for me any other ideas out there ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Set the taskbar to Auto-hide.
2. Reboot.
3. Set taskbar NOT to auto-hide.
4. Reboot again.

Comment: This is not a good solution. The issue does not start at reboot, so why do I have to reboot TWICE to make it go away? There has to be a better way.