# Window goes beyond the taskbar in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 taskbar hides other windows' status bar](https://superuser.com/questions/88285/windows-7-taskbar-hides-other-windows-status-bar)

When I a drag window left or right, it goes beyond the taskbar as in the picture:
[image: example window position]
How can I prevent this ? So when I maximize a window or drag it to the edge, I want it to stretch until the taskbar, not beyond it.

Comment: Is this happening when you snap windows to the edges and maximizes them, or is it only when dragging the windows with the mouse?

Comment: Do you have the feature **Auto-hide the taskbar** enabled?